# Changing info in an Array in local storage a with checkbox click

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I have two arrays that correspond 1 to 1, one has class names, one has a "y" or "n" if it's been taken. These two arrays are turned into strings with JSON.stringify in the local storage then parsed out in the html.

So far I've gotten them to sort based off the arrays stored in local storage and populate the divs #classesTaken and #classes not taken. What I need is for when the user clicks on the checkbox it goes into the array inside local storage and switches a "y" to "n" or "n" to "y".
Then when I refresh the page it resorts the array appropriately. I am using JqueryMobile to design the application and am using multiple pages in one page. this is my code so far.

```
function myFunction() {
    var cn2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('className'));
    var ct2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('classTaken'));

    for (var i = 0; i < ct2.length; i++) {
        var info = '<li>' + '<input type="checkbox" class="myCheckbox" id=["a" + i]> <br>' + cn2[i] + ' id# ' + i + '</li>'

        $('#myCheckbox').click(function () {
                if (ct2[i] = "y") {
                    ct2[i] = "n"
                } else {
                    ct2[i] = "y";
                }

            });
        if (ct2[i] == "y") {
            $('#classesTaken').append(info);
        } else {
            $('#classesNotTaken').append(info);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you access the elements in a loop? You only will add many event listeners that all do the same thing to the same element.

Comment: The idea is that it checks every checkbox for each class.